# TFS cannot retrieve the list of team projects

Tags: tfs

When I trying to access to list of my project from TFS, the error message as following prompting out

*TF31001: Team Foundation cannot retrieve the list of team projects from Team Foundation Server 10.0.80.50. The Team Foundation Server returned the following error: Error creating the Web Proxy specified in the 'system.net/defaultProxy' configuration section..*

Does anyone facing this problem before and how do you solve it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Team Explorer connects via web service to TFS.  It sounds like you have a config issue with the proxy settings in IE that is preventing you from connecting to your server.

Try navigating to one of the web services directly using IE (e.g. http://yourtfsservername:8080/Services/v1.0/ServerStatus.asmx) and see if you get an error.  If so, check your proxy settings - if they look OK, see if you can exclude the TFS server from being accessed via the proxy and go direct instead.

Comment: someone can try out Richard's solution if you are facing this kind of same problem. I end up re-format my machine and everything is working fine again.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error out of sudden. Spent some time with my colleagues playing with different ways of launching Visual Studio 2008 and its configuration settings. I have found a couple of ways to bypass this error, although still don’t know what the original cause is. 1) Start VS with command line like this: devenv.exe /resetaddin. 2) Comment out the system.net setting within the devenv.exe.config. Like this:

```
<system.net>
<!-- <settings>
        <ipv6 enabled="true"/>
     </settings>
 -->
</system.net>
```

They both work. I found the second option is more continent. Without this ipv6 setting I am not sure what else may be affected. But, at least I can make an emergency connection to my TFS server to check-in some files.

Comment: Thank you so very much John!!  This was a life saver for me!!!  

For future searchers: that it took two restarts of VS to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

John Cheng's answer was so helpful. I changed the devenv.exe.config file like he mentioned and was able to connect to TFS.  Before that, I had even tried re-installing Team Explorer to no benefit.