# Visual Studio internet connection failue

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, internet-connection

Last night my Visual Studio was working fine.  Today it fails to connect to the internet (can't download rss feeds or connect to my TFS Server).

My internet connection is working fine (I am using it to write this).

What could cause this?  Are there settings that I can get at to fix it?

The only clue I have is that Resharper is giving me some weird errors.

```
System.ArgumentException: Invalid XML. Missing required tag  for type 'System.Security.Policy.PolicyStatement'.
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for system.net/settings: Invalid XML. Missing required tag  for type 'System.Security.Policy.PolicyStatement'. (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.Config line 155) ---> System.ArgumentException: Invalid XML. Missing required tag  for type 'System.Security.Policy.PolicyStatement'.
```

I have checked the file it mentions (devenv.exe.Config) and it is the same as a coworkers who is having no issues.

Things I have tried:

- Disabling Resharper

  - Causes the error message to go away, but does not fix the issue.
- Rebooting
- System Restore
- "netsh Winsock reset" + reboot

Any advice would be appreciated.

---

More info:
When I try to connect to my TFS Server I get this error:

```
TF31001: Team Foundation cannot retrieve the list of team projects from Team Foundation Server MyTFSServer. The Team Foundation Server returned the following error: Error creating the Web Proxy specified in the 'system.net/defaultProxy' configuration section..
```

I have no idea what that means

Comment: Maybe it is a problem with your proxy settings

Comment: Do those change on their own?  (I don't even know where to change them so I am fairly sure I did not do it deliberately.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question was similar:

[TFS cannot retrieve the list of team projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708631/tfs-cannot-retrieve-the-list-of-team-projects/1334845#1334845)

I have no idea why this broke or what the real "Fix is" but here is the work around in that thread (not the accepted answer, but should be).

Comment out the system.net setting within the Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config. Like this:

```
<system.net>
<!-- <settings>
        <ipv6 enabled="true"/>
     </settings>
 -->
</system.net>
```

Kudos to John Cheng for figuring this out!

(If anyone finds out why this happens and what the real fix is I will accept that as the answer.)

Comment: I commented out the entire system.net section and it magically worked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried uninstalling Reshaper?

Perhaps "Repairing" Visual Studio after that? Perhaps a reinstall of SP1 for VS2008 might help.